# How accessibility access is secure?

Tags: accessibility

My android device is rooted and running Android 4.4.2.

Some apps like **App Lock**, **GO Power Master**, **Kaspersky Internet Security**, **All-In-One-Toolbox**, **MoboClean Auto Installer** ask for accessibility access for better performance.

All the above apps assure me that they are not gathering any personal information, but while giving access I see a message saying they observe actions and retrieve window content.

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Accessibility will become a bit more secure: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-threatening-removal-accessibility-services-play-store/ ... in short: Google probably will remove apps that abuse accessibility functions.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, it *isn't* secure.  Do not give any apps extra permissions or increased access that you do not trust them with.  Once you give them access to your data, they have the opportunity to abuse it.

Comment: I do agree. That's why I didn't allow accessibility access to any apps but be it App Lock, GO Power Master, Kaspersky Internet Security or All-In-One-Toolbox. While allowing accessibility access I see a message saying they observe actions and retrieve window content. Even I see same message for Kaspersky Internet Security for Android.